# UIActivityViewController Style in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am new to ios and I have a problem on displaying UIActivityViewController. I have done the code and it works fine on ios8&9 iPad, but when I tested on ios10 iPad 5th and the UIActivityViewController frame was restricted by its parent view controller.

Problem need to be fixed:
[image: Test on ios10 ipad5]

The desired layout:

[image: Test on ios8&9]

```
UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

vc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage];
vc.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.shareButton;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 
UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
```

Can anyone give me some hints on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you present the `vc`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];